# jade, импорт миксина + custom class?

Tags: gulp, jade, tars

Добрый день, импортирую миксин

```
include ../button/button
```

на странице пишу

```
+button('Custom Title').red
```

Тем не менее класс red не добавляется

Answer (score 0):

Aттрибуты не передаются напрямую, для этого используйте `&attributes(attributes)`

```
mixin button()
  button(type="button").button&attributes(attributes)
    block

+button().button_color_red Button
```

https://codepen.io/Zoxon/pen/PQNXvE